# Adding C# to webform with master page

Tags: c#, html, button

I want to add my code to sent an email via C# but my button doesn't seems to work.

HTML Code:

```
<div style="text-align:center">
    <p style="background-color: Yellow">if you have a video that you think should be here send it to us</p>Name:
    <input type="text" id="Name" />Link:
    <input type="text" id="Link" />
    <br />Why you think this video should be here:
    <br />
    <textarea id="Why" rows="5" cols="50"></textarea>
    <br />
    <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Send" style="height: 25px; width: 200px" />
</div>
```

aspx.cs Code:

```
public partial class Videos : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public string Answer;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Answer = "Email Sent2";
        if (Request.Form["submit"] != null)
        {
            Answer = "Email Sent3";
            string Name = Request.Form["Name"];
            string Link = Request.Form["Link"];
            string Why = Request.Form["Why"];
            string body = "<div dir='ltr'>";
            body += ("<h4>You got a new video idea from </h4>");
            body += (Name);
            body += ("<br />");
            body += ("Link: " + Link);
            body += ("<br />");
            body += ("Reason: " + Why);
            body += ("</div>");

            var client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
            {
                Credentials = new NetworkCredential("MY EMAIL", "MY PASS"),
                EnableSsl = true
            };
            System.Net.Mail.MailMessage mail1 = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();
            mail1.Body = body;
            mail1.From = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("MY EMAIL");
            mail1.IsBodyHtml = true;
            mail1.Subject = "Vidoe Idea By " + Name;
            mail1.To.Add("MY EMAI");

            client.Send(mail1);
            Answer = "Email Sent";
        }
    }
```

I don't know why but when I press the button nothing happend.
What is the problem here?

Comment: Have you got a problem with your keyboard? try an asp:button control instead of an HTML input

Comment: First, debug your code because "I press the button nothing happend" is an user issue, not a programmer one.. and here is about programming issues. Second, I don't know if you can read simple <input> HTML with webforms, why don't you use <input id="txtName" runat="server" /> and read this in C# as txtName.Text instead Request.Form? So, debug your code, search where it doesn't works and tell us again.

Comment: i debuged my code. it all works until the if(Request.Form..

Comment: Or, to differentiate in general between submitting or loading for the first time (as I suspect you're trying to do) just use `IsPostBack`.

Comment: You seem to be missing the point of webforms some what. Are you coming from a PHP or Classic ASP background? Perhaps ASP.net MVC would suit you more. Also look into `StringBuilder` to replace the sting concatination you are doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do some more research on how Webforms work in ASP.net.

Webforms are designed to work in tandem with server controls, which you will find in the toolbar in VisualStudio. The request object will still work and is the backbone of webforms. Note though, that the request object requires a `name` attribute. In terms of HTML objects, `ID` is for client-side, `name` is for server side. This is some what an oversimplification but is a useful guideline.

Webforms is also heavily event orientated an you should take advantage of this fact and use a click event for the button.

I would use something like the following:

**HTML/aspx**

```
<div style="text-align:center">
    <p style="background-color: Yellow">if you have a video that you think should be here send it to us</p>
    <!-- Use Label to create a label associated with the control
    This is good practice -->
    <asp:Label id="lblName" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="txtName" EnableViewState="false">Name:</asp:Label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <br /><!-- Not really best practice to use <br /> for formatting, use CSS instead --> 
    <asp:Label ID="lblLink" runat="server" EnableViewState="false" AssociatedControlID="txtLink">Link</asp:Label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtLink" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <br />
    <asp:Label ID="lblWhy" runat="server" EnableViewState="false" AssociatedControlID="txtWhy">Why you think this video should be here:</asp:Label>
    <br />
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtWhy" TextMode="MultiLine" Rows="5" Columns="50" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <br />
    <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server"  Text="Send" 
           style="height: 25px; width: 200px" onclick="btnSubmit_Click"/>
<!-- A Message to display when email has been sent -->
<asp:Panel ID="pnlSucess" runat="server" Visible="false">Your feed back is appreciated!</asp:Panel>
</div>
```

**.aspx.cs**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Note: Nothing Here... 
    //Use this event for setting the page up
}

//Use this event for handling the click
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //MAKE SURE YOU USE ERROR HANDLING FOR THE REAL WORLD

    string Answer = string.Empty;
    Answer = "Email Sent3";
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

    //NOTE: You should be sanitising client input
    string Name = txtName.Text;
    string Link = txtLink.Text;
    string Why = txtWhy.Text;

    //String builder is a better way to build a string
    //or look at string.Format();            
    builder.Append("<div dir='ltr'>");
    builder.AppendLine("<h4>You got a new video idea from </h4>");
    builder.AppendLine(Name);
    builder.AppendLine("<br />");
    builder.AppendLine("Link: ");
    builder.Append(Link);
    builder.AppendLine("<br />");
    builder.AppendLine("Reason: ");
    builder.Append(Why);
    builder.AppendLine("</div>");

    var client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
    {
        Credentials = new NetworkCredential("MY EMAIL", "MY PASS"),
        EnableSsl = true
    };
    System.Net.Mail.MailMessage mail1 = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();
    mail1.Body = builder.ToString(); //Get the body
    mail1.From = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("MY EMAIL");
    mail1.IsBodyHtml = true;
    mail1.Subject = "Vidoe Idea By " + Name;
    mail1.To.Add("MY EMAI");

    client.Send(mail1);
    Answer = "Email Sent";

    //Display a message so the user knows it worked!
    pnlSucess.Visible = true;
}
```

Make sure to add `using System.Net;` to the using statements at the top of the code behind. This is required for the `StringBuilder`.

Answer (score 0):

If your are using web forms you better use the web form controls. The elements:

```
<input type="text" id="Name" />Link:
<input type="text" id="Link" />
```

Doesn't have a runat="server" tag and the id, this is necessary to read the content of those input in server side code.

And you have to use a asp:button then assign an event to run the send email code. If you use this event page load with out an if checking if it is a post back to can get a lot of email sent by this code.

My recommendation create a new web form, add asp:textbox for your input and asp:button for your input create the event in the button and add the code there. Read the content with the text property and debug your code.